# Rotate element on each click

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to rotate an element on each click like this: https://uimovement.com/design/addition-subtraction/

I tried this:

`element.style = 'tranform: rotate(90deg)'`

But this adds style only once. I want to rotate it on each click. How do I do that?

I tried adding a class. But when I click once, the class gets added, so I cannot add again. If I remove the class to enable rotate on next click, the rotate happens in the reverse direction.

**Edit** : https://jsfiddle.net/8pue5nra/

Comment: can you show your code? in stackblitz if possible

Comment: @Mamta here: https://jsfiddle.net/8pue5nra/  it rotates only once. I want to rotate every time it is clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a function and you have to change the angle on every click. Add a counter and multiply it with 90 for every click to rotate it every time on click.

```js
var count=0;
function rot(e){
count++;
var deg=count*90;
 e.style.transform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
}
```

```css
#box
{
height:20px;
width:70px;
background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="rot(this)"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the `count++` might want to be below the `*90`?

Comment: count is initialized to zero. If it is incremented below multiplication there will be no rotation on the first click as the angle will become 0

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
const el = document.querySelector('#btn');
let degrees = 0;

el.addEventListener('click', function(){
  degrees += 90;
  this.style = `transform: rotate(${degrees}deg)`;
})
```